# Password lifetimes, length, complexity and history. Is there something to help?

Tags: linux, password, password-management

I need to implement some better control for passwords on a our slackware servers. I have always manually done this but the need for some automation routines to handle a lifetime check, length, complexity and history. Does anyone know of a utility that can assist me in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For password lifetimes, you can set the maximum age in `/etc/login.defs`. For length and complexity checks, that's a feature of `pam_cracklib`, which should be enabled somewhere in `/etc/pam.d/`. You can read the man page for a list of all the options.

Unfortunately I haven't seen anything that keeps track of a password history, the best cracklib can do is compare against the previous password.

Comment: Slack doesn't do PAM. Or it hasn't done it in the past, I haven't played with it in a while.

You can always test your shadow file with John the Ripper and some wordlists.

Comment: pam_cracklib can remember more than 1 previous password.  The documentation suggests that the realistic limit to this is about 400 previous passwords per user due to internal limits.